# Is there any way of bringing variables from state into a random typescript file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, state, vuex, store

I am using vue.js with vuetify. I have a value stored in state (using `Vuex`) that is defined in `scr/store/index.ts` (a boolean called `darkMode`)which I use in one of my view components inside a `.vue` file. I want, however, to use the same variable in the `typescript` file in which I have my vuetify settings (`src/plugins/vuetify.ts`). Is that even possible? I am new to vue.js/vuetify/typescript.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.ts

import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    dark: darkMode, // <--- HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO USE MY VARIABLE FROM STATE
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#32A4A0",
        secondary: "#C83C96",
        background: "#FFFFFF",
        border: "BEBEBE",
        warning: "#FFE011",
        error: "#F40808",
      },
      dark: {
        primary: "#4EC0EB",
        secondary: "#FF79C0",
        background: "#353535",
        border: "BEBEBE",
        warning: "#FFE011",
        error: "#F40808",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
src
---store
------index.ts
---plugins
------vuetify.ts
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. It was just a matter of importing the store object:

```
import store from "../store/index";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is bind the dark mode to the store value.  The settings you pass in initially are just initialisation values.  So you need to do this:

```
<v-app :dark="darkMode">
```

and then have a computed property to get the darkMode from the store

```
computed: {
    darkMode() {
      return store.index.darkMode
    }
  }
```

darkMode should then be reactive and update the dark value in the v-app bound to it.
not tested it but hopefully get you going in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tim. The actual activation of the dark mode theme works fine. My problem is that on page refresh the `vuetify -> theme.dark` value is set back to the default (which in my case is the OS default). What I want is to be able to do is to make `Vuetify` use my persisted state as the boolean for `theme.dark`.